# React: Incorporating event listening into web3js promise

Tags: web3js, react

I have the following React component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      id: this.props.id,
      age: 0,
      web3: null,
    }
    this.setAge= this.setAge.bind(this)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    getWeb3
    .then(results => {
      this.setState({
        web3: results.web3
      })
      this.getData()
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log('Error finding web3.')
    })
  }

  getData(){
    const contract = require('truffle-contract')
    const book = contract(Book)
    book.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider)

    var bookInstance

    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
      book.deployed().then((instance) => {
        bookInstance = instance

        return bookInstance.ageOf.call(this.props.id, {from: accounts[0]})
      }).then((result) => {
        return this.setState({age: result})
      })
    })
  }

setAge() {
    const contract = require('truffle-contract')
    const book = contract(Book)
    book.setProvider(this.state.web3.currentProvider)

    var bookInstance

    this.state.web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
      book.deployed().then((instance) => {
        bookInstance = instance

        return bookInstance.ageOf.call(this.props.id, {from: accounts[0]})
      }).then((result) => {
        return bookInstance.setAge(this.props.id, {from: accounts[0], value: result, gas: 1000000, gasPrice: this.state.web3.toWei(10, 'gwei')})
      })
    })
  })
}

render() {
     return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.setAge}>set age</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default Parent
```

I have the function `setAge()` that fires a Solidity event called `ageSet(uint256 id, uint256 age)`. I want to listen to the event to alert a message of success, but can't figure it out how to incorporate event listening into the code. What would be the best way?

Answer (score 1):

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#events-allevents

You can do this in your componentWillMount for example:
Assuming contract is the instance of the deployed contract

```
    contract.allEvents({
        fromBlock: 'latest',
    }, function (error, event) {
        if (error)
            alert("error while subscribing to event")
        console.log(event)
        }
    })
```

This will listen for events from the latest block. That means you won't get past events, but there is an api for that too:

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents